# CSS3 nth-of-type and first-child before

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

I have a problem with nth-of-type(odd):before and first-child:before
I need to disable :before content in first "li" element.
**Problem is that css don't react to first-child:before..**

*P.S I'm using LESS*

So, there is a code:

```
li {
    &:first-child {
        &:before {
            content:none;
        }
    }

    &:nth-of-type(odd) {
        &:before {
            content:'\b7';
            margin:0 8px 0 5px;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`li:first-child` and `li:nth-of-type(odd)` will both match the same element, so in this case your second rule is completely overriding the first.

The simplest way around this is to move your first rule below, since [both of your selectors are equally specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity) (1 element, 1 pseudo-class, 1 pseudo-element):

```
li {
    &:nth-of-type(odd) {
        &:before {
            content:'\b7';
            margin:0 8px 0 5px;
        }
    }

    &:first-child {
        &:before {
            content:none;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that because both selectors are matching the same element, the `margin` style will still apply to the first child's `:before`. But since you're using `content:none` in the second rule, [you're effectively disabling the `:before` pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content), so you shouldn't need to change anything else.

That said, if you want to cancel it out explicitly anyway, you can:

```
li {
    &:nth-of-type(odd) {
        &:before {
            content:'\b7';
            margin:0 8px 0 5px;
        }
    }

    &:first-child {
        &:before {
            content:none;
            margin:0;
        }
    }
}
```